# UICollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath doesn't call didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collection view. I would like to programmatically select a cell. This is the code I use

```
[_collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentSelectedVideo inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

For some reason the functions:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Are not called and therefore the visual effect I am using for showing the selected cell is not shown on the screen.

Is it a proper behavior?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, this is proper behaviour. Documentation for
[selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:] says:

> This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called.

Answer (score 39):

You can make it.

```
[self.collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
[self collectionView:self.collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

if use only selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: method, don't call delegate method.
if use only collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: method, it don't work stabil

happy code :)

Comment: This should be voted as an answer as well, whilst not the perfect way (calling a delegate method manually) it works nicely and has helped me out on numerous occasions!

Comment: I tried to call these from viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, but no luck! The methods do get called as I am hitting the breakpoints but my visual effect for showing the selected cell does not take effect.

Answer (score 3):

Osmenda's answer in Swift with my custom collection view:

```
self.collectionView(calendarCV, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4:**

```
self.collectionView(daysCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
```